# Parsing JSON message in Spark from Kafka stream

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have an event stream (format below ) that I need to parse in spark ( java ). I am able to read the stream but haven't been able to find an example to convert the message to java bean.

```
{
    user_id  : string,
    session_id : string,
    event : string,
    page : string,
    timestamp : timestamp
}
```

Java Bean

```
public class Event implements Serializable {

    private String user_id;

    private String session_id;
    private String page;
    private String event;
    private Timestamp timestamp;
}
```

Code to read the message as String.

```
Dataset<String> lines = spark
                        .readStream()
                        .format("kafka")
                        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
                        .option("subscribe", topics)
                        .load()
                        .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
                        .as(Encoders.STRING());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work using following approach.

```
        FlatMapFunction<String, Event> linesToEvents = new FlatMapFunction<String, Event>() {
            @Override
            public Iterator<Event> call(String line) throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {
                ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                ArrayList<Event> eventList = new ArrayList<>();
                eventList.add(mapper.readValue(line, Event.class));
                return eventList.iterator();
            }
        };
```

```
        Dataset<Event> lines = spark
                                .readStream()
                                .format("kafka")
                                .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
                                .option("subscribe", topics)
                                .load()
                                .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
                                .as(Encoders.STRING())
                                .flatMap(linesToEvents, Encoders.bean(Event.class));
```